# Send Custom mail template in laravel nova while reseting password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I am using laravel nova for my dashboard. While reseting password, i want to use a custom mail template for the mail, but I am not being able to send it.
The `NovaServiceProvider.php` uses `Nove::routes()` along with password reset routes(). I am ok with use of those routes but i just want to modify the mail send from that route.